# How to type questions and answers with MathJax quickly on Android?

Tags: support, mathjax

I am an Android user and I normally use my mobile phone to access Mathematics Stack Exchange. We all know that typing TeX using mobile devices is not an easy task. My question is "is there any special method or an app available for Android users to type questions and answers quickly and easily on Mathematics Stack Exchange?".

Comment: I do this often enough to consider myself "practiced" at it.  The only real shortcuts are the ones where holding down a key in alphabetic mode produces a symbol (shown on the screen keyboard).  Most of the special characters are available this way, but caret (^) is a significant exception.

Comment: I use mobile pretty much exclusively because I hardly use my computer anymore for anything but work, and I answer questions. I use the mobile app. It's a pain, and I end up writing answers that are less detailed because the little nuances are annoying to type.

Answer (score 12):

Sadly, no. Mobile devices are meant to *consume* content, not to *create* it. This is true for news (most journalist and editors use laptops or PCs to write their articles, even though most people read it on mobile devices) but it holds for Stack Exchange as well.

There is no preview option on the mobile website of Stack Exchange (though there is one on the iOS app, I'm not sure about the Android app), which makes posting even more difficult. I could imagine somebody taking the time to write a custom keyboard supporting the most common TeX commands (and the opening and closing `$`) like `\frac`, `\log` etc.; this would certainly help a little.

<sub>(*not* sent from my iPhone)</sub>